# QSortFilterProxyModel sort by Date

Tags: c++, qt, sorting, qt5, qsortfilterproxymodel

I want to sort a table by dates. The problem is that they are interpreted as strings, hence my local date format is sorted wrongly, like `26. September` is bigger than `16. November`, because `26 > 16`.

Anyway, so I have my own model set up and tried it like this:

```
QVariant MyModel::data(const QModelIndex &index, int role) const
{
    if(role == Qt::UserRole)
    {
        if(index.column() == 5) // Date
           return QSqlTableModel::data(index, role).toDate();
    }

    if(role == Qt::DisplayRole)
    {
        if(index.column() == 5) // Date
           return QSqlTableModel::data(index.role).toDate().toString("dd MMMM yyyy");
    }
}
```

and I set the `sortRole` like this:

```
proxyModel->setSortRole(Qt::UserRole);
```

The corresponding lines actually get called, but now I cant sort the table at all. It's just not responding. The arrows (representing asc or desc ordering) at the corresponding columns are changing, but the data isn't.
**Of course I set the rest like:**

```
proxyModel->setDynamicSortFilter(true);
proxyModel->setSourceModel(myDBModel);
proxyModel->setFilterKeyColumn(1);
proxyModel->setFilterCaseSensitivity(Qt::CaseInsensitive);
```

If I do not set the `sortRole` at least I can sort by the other columns correctly.
What am I doing wrong here? Do I have to implement another function or anything? I looked around the internet, but all I found was problems with sorting integers from years back, never dates :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am an idiot (fact!)

Qt already provided all I needed, it was just a stupid mistake on my side. Two things, really:

```
   if(role == Qt::UserRole)
    {
        if(index.column() == 5)
            return QDate::fromString(QSqlTableModel::data(index, Qt::DisplayRole).toString(), "yyyy-MM-dd"); // 1st Mistake, no correct conversion. I always got QVariant(invalid)
// 1.1 Mistake, also, grab the data from Qt::DisplayRole, not from Qt::UserRole!

        return QSqlTableModel::data(index, Qt::DisplayRole); // 2nd Mistake. Because I didn't add that line I couldn't sort it on any other column anymore. When I finally could sort it on the dates I couldn't on the other columns, then I thought about adding this line et voila!
    }
```

I wanna thank you for your kind and fast answers, but the problem existed between chair and keyboard this time.

Answer (score 1):

I think that you should use Custom Sort/Filter Model. You should "teach" class how to compare it. Take a look of this example: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwidgets-itemviews-customsortfiltermodel-example.html

I think that the most useful code for you, you can find here:

```
bool MySortFilterProxyModel::lessThan(const QModelIndex &left,
                                       const QModelIndex &right) const
 {
     QVariant leftData = sourceModel()->data(left);
     QVariant rightData = sourceModel()->data(right);

     if (leftData.type() == QVariant::DateTime) 
         return leftData.toDateTime() < rightData.toDateTime();
}
```

`QDateTime` already has overloaded operator `<`.

Answer (score 1):

According to the QSortFilterProxyModel documentation, you can provide your own implementation of lessThan(). http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsortfilterproxymodel.html#lessThan

If for some reason that doesn't work as expected, you can always sort the dates as strings if you format those dates using ISO8601 (YYYY-MM-DD). This is how I typically choose to store (and later sort) dates when dealing with databases.